# C# server Socket to Android Socket over NAT

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, nat

The Android app is behind a NAT (3G connection) , while the server is on a public IP.

The Android app can connect to the server socket and send data (via Socket/TCPclient on android) but the server cannot connect to the Android port because of the NATs 
(server getting "... has failed to respond "ip_adress_of_android : port_that_is_open_and_listening_on_android".

Is there anyway to overcome this, or some parameters I can use in order for the server connection attempt to reach it's destination over the NATs without using a custom library? - or could you please point me to an easy to implement method, I don't have time to study and integrate a complicated 3rd party library

Here is a sample of how my server code works:

```
int port_server, port_android;  // used to declare used ports by the server and android   
Socket server_socket, client_socket; //sockets used to receive and send data

server_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);                           
server_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port_server));                                                        
server_socket.Listen(0);

public void listen()
{
server_socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
                client_socket = server_socket.EndAccept(AR);                                                                            
                buffer = new byte[client_socket.ReceiveBufferSize];                                                                     
                client_socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
        listen(); // to continue listening to the port
        // code that does something with the data
        send_string("Take this"); // sends a string to android
        }
public void send_string(string notif)
        {
            string ip_client = client_socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();                                                  
            string ip_client2 = (ip_c.Split(':'))[0];                                                               
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip_client, port_android);                                             
            Byte[] notifi = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(notif);                                   
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();                                                              
            stream.Write(notifi, 0, notifi.Length);                                                         
            stream.Close();                                                                                         
            client.Close();                                                                                         
        }
```

I should note that they work both ways when on a LAN, so the code is working, I only need to modify is so that it can reach android targets over NATs.

Comment: You can send data back via client_socket. There is no way to break through NAT, unless NAT is configured with port forwarding. But once connection established you can transfer data in both ways.

Comment: You mean that I can send back data through the connection established by the Android to the server?How?I can't get any options on the server side of the connection to put string in it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
class Program
{
    int port_server = 42424;
    Socket server_socket;

    public Program()
    {
        server_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port_server));
        server_socket.Listen(0);
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = server_socket.Accept();
            var buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), Tuple.Create(client, buffer));
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        var state = (Tuple<Socket, byte[]>)AR.AsyncState;
        var client = state.Item1;
        var buffer = state.Item2;
        byte[] notifi = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Take this");
        client.Send(notifi);
        client.Close();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var programm = new Program();
        programm.Listen();
    }
}
```

client part

```
using (Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 42424));
    client.Send(new byte[] {1, 2, 3}, SocketFlags.None);
    byte[] bt = new byte[256];
    client.Receive(bt, 256, SocketFlags.None);
}
```